# Javascript confetti blast effect

Tags: javascript, animation

I was able to find this code to create a javascript confetti blast.
However, I need three main colours for the confetti, and for the confetti, to be squares. Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is the code

```js
// shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
    function( callback ){
   window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
 W = window.innerWidth,
 H = window.innerHeight,
 circles = [];

canvas.width = W;
canvas.height = H; 

//Random Circles creator
function create() {
 
 //Place the circles at the center
 
 this.x = W/2;
 this.y = H/2;

 
 //Random radius between 2 and 6
 this.radius = 2 + Math.random()*3; 
 
 //Random velocities
 this.vx = -5 + Math.random()*10;
 this.vy = -5 + Math.random()*10;
 
 //Random colors
 this.r = Math.round(Math.random())*255;
 this.g = Math.round(Math.random())*255;
 this.b = Math.round(Math.random())*255;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
 circles.push(new create());
}

function draw() {
 
 //Fill canvas with black color
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.15)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
 
 //Fill the canvas with circles
 for(var j = 0; j < circles.length; j++){
  var c = circles[j];
  
  //Create the circles
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+c.r+", "+c.g+", "+c.b+", 1)";
  ctx.fill();
  
  c.x += c.vx;
  c.y += c.vy;
  c.radius -= .02;
  
  if(c.radius > 3)
   circles[j] = new create();
 }
}

function animate() {
 requestAnimFrame(animate);
 draw();
}

animate();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
 
 body{
 padding: 0; margin: 0;
 min-height: 400px; height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #000000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="explosion.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D for the canvas 2D API

Comment: Hi Suppen, I figured that I need to change the "this.r"," this.g" and "this.b", to colour values, I'm looking how else, to do this, I'm not sure that I have here is correct?
this.r='#f2b115';

Comment: r, g and b are values between 0 and 255 inclusive, not hexadecimals. Also, if you want answers to your question, you should write what you have tried to do and why what you tried doesn't work. This is not a site where you ask people to fix your code, but a site where you ask what you are doing wrong.

Comment: awesome, thank you, will do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code, thank you Stephen Brickner for all the help. I've learned a hell of alot

```
    // shim layer with setTimeout fallback
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
              window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
              function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
              };
    })();

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        W = window.innerWidth,
        H = window.innerHeight,
        circles = [];

    canvas.width = W;
    canvas.height = H; 

    //Random Circles creator
    function create() {

        //Place the circles at the center

        this.x = W/2;
        this.y = H/2;


        //Random radius between 2 and 6
        this.radius = 2 + Math.random()*3; 

        //Random velocities
        this.vx = -10 + Math.random()*30;
        this.vy = -10 + Math.random()*30;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        circles.push(new create());
    }

    function draw() {

        //Fill canvas with black color
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(175,38,28,255)";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

        var myColors = ["e8e8e8", "a98547", "ccac7b"];
        var which = 0;

        //Fill the canvas with circles
        for(var j = 0; j < circles.length; j++){
            var c = circles[j];

            //Create the circles
            ctx.beginPath();
            //ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
            ctx.fillRect(c.x , c.y, 8, 8); //change to box

            //ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+c.r+", "+c.g+", "+c.b+", 1)";
            ctx.fillStyle = "#" + myColors[which].toString();
            ctx.fill();

            c.x += c.vx;
            c.y += c.vy;
            c.radius -= .02;

            if(c.radius > 3)
                circles[j] = new create();

            if(which < myColors.length - 1) {
                which++;
            }
            else {
                which = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimFrame(animate);
        draw();
    }

    animate();
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up an alternative solution. I noticed your current solutions had some runtime error, also a lot of unnecessary code (IMO - might be cleaner or easier to read?) and painted the whole rectangle canvas, you could apply this as a background colour via CSS, or leave as transparent as you probably want the confetti to show over something?

https://codepen.io/BenMoses/pen/MWyEePJ

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; //not needed as is default.
// shim layer with setTimeout fallback ? This is globally support so probably unnecessary?
//this.radius = 2 + Math.random()*3;  //this is only for circles so can be removed
// all circle references should be updated to rect or square or confetti and confetto (a single confetti :o )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are just a couple of places to modify (commented below).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        padding: 0; margin: 0;
        min-height: 400px; height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        // shim layer with setTimeout fallback
        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
          return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
                  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
                  window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
                  window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
                  function( callback ){
                    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                  };
        })();

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            W = window.innerWidth,
            H = window.innerHeight,
            circles = [];

        canvas.width = W;
        canvas.height = H; 

        //Random Circles creator
        function create() {

            //Place the circles at the center

            this.x = W/2;
            this.y = H/2;


            //Random radius between 2 and 6
            this.radius = 2 + Math.random()*3; 

            //Random velocities
            this.vx = -5 + Math.random()*10;
            this.vy = -5 + Math.random()*10;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            circles.push(new create());
        }

        function draw() {

            //Fill canvas with black color
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.15)";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

            var myColors = ["e8e8e8", "a98547", "ccac7b"];
            var which = 0;

            //Fill the canvas with circles
            for(var j = 0; j < circles.length; j++){
                var c = circles[j];

                //Create the circles
                ctx.beginPath();
                //ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                ctx.fillRect(c.x , c.y, 20, 20); //change to box

                //ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+c.r+", "+c.g+", "+c.b+", 1)";
                ctx.fillStyle = "#" + myColors[which].toString();
                ctx.fill();

                c.x += c.vx;
                c.y += c.vy;
                c.radius -= .02;

                if(c.radius > 3)
                    circles[j] = new create();

                if(which < myColors.length - 1) {
                    which++;
                }
                else {
                    which = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimFrame(animate);
            draw();
        }

        animate();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen , however I tried changing the colours to
below, but no luck, do you know why?

this.r = 0xe8e8e8 ; //add your colors here
this.g = 0xa98547 ;
this.b = 0xccac7b ;

Comment: I made an update to the answer. You just need to loop through your color array if you are trying to constrain it to just 3 colors.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the index and use [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) to determine what color to set. Basic idea:

```
function create(ind) {

    /* other code */    

    if(ind%3===0) { /* set color one */ }
    else if (ind%2===0) { /* set color two */ }
    else { /* set color three */ }     
}

for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    circles.push(new create(i));
}
```

Hopefully you figure out you need to change the `this.r`, `this.g`, and `this.b` values to match the color you need.